# Como aplicar efeito hover num elemento imediatamente antes?

Tags: html, css

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
<div>
   <img src="#">
   <button>Teste</button>
</div>
<div>
   <img src="#">
   <button>Teste</button>
</div>
```

Preciso que quando ao repousar o mouse sobre um botão na imagem imediatamente antes dele seja aplicado o efeito `transform:scale(1.5)`

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer? Coloca o código na pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Você quer que seja aplicado o efeito na imagem ou no botão? Caso queira o efeito no botão é só substituir `img` por `button`. Seria essa sua dúvida?

```css
img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div>
   <img src="#">
   <button>Teste</button>
</div>
<div>
   <img src="#">
   <button>Teste</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Não, passa o mouse sobre o botão e aplica o efeito na imagem

Comment: Consigo fazer com o elemento imediatamente depois, mas imediatamente antes não consigo dá